# Why have the GAE cold starts gotten worse lately?

Tags: google-app-engine

For some time the cold start times for GAE applications have been ok, but now they have started to be really long again. Now (since a couple of days ago) it usually takes many seconds to access a webpage from an app with low traffic. That's totally unacceptable long time for ordinary webpages.

Comment: I suggest you to create an issue in http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/, this question does not belong here since is too localized.